# Typescript compiler not showing error

Tags: typescript

According to Typescript documentation when using object literal it should exactly match interface. But for the following code playground does not show any error message:

[image: code pic from playground]

Here prop is string so it conflicts with `[index: number]: number` which means the index should be a number and value at that index should be a number, for properties other than `name` and `age`.

Is it a bug? If I am wrong please explain how this is working?

Comment: Do not post images of code.

Comment: I posted it to point out no error is being showed in playground.

Comment: It's very easy to generate a link for a playground example. This way, people trying to answer your question can quickly check the code out. Otherwise just pasting the code here, so a reviewer can try to compile it is always a better alternative then a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify more properties than the interface requires. As demonstration, have a look at this code: ([or on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20obligatoryProperty%3A%20string%0A%20%20optionalProperty%3F%3A%20string%0A%20%20%5Bindex%3A%20number%5D%3A%20number%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20impl1%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20fails%20compilation%0Alet%20impl2%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20%7B%20obligatoryProperty%3A%20'hello'%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20compiles%20fine%0Alet%20impl3%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20obligatoryProperty%3A%20'hello'%2C%0A%20%20optionalProperty%3A%20'hello'%2C%0A%20%202%3A%202%2C%0A%20%203%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20notSpecifiedProperty%3A%20'hello'%2C%0A%7D%20%2F%2F%20Still%20fine%0A))

```
// index.ts
interface MyInterface {
  obligatoryProperty: string
  optionalProperty?: string
  [index: number]: number  
}

let impl1: MyInterface = {} // fails compilation
let impl2: MyInterface = { obligatoryProperty: 'hello' } // compiles fine
let impl3: MyInterface = {
  obligatoryProperty: 'hello',
  optionalProperty: 'hello',
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  notSpecifiedPropertyThatIsAlsoNotANumber: 'hello',
} // Still fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they decided to do "implicit index signatures", which is a good thing! You can read about the reasons here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7059

**But** the TypeScript compiler will show an error if you create a property that has a `number` as key and a non-`number` as value. [Here is an example in the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Thing%20%7B%0A%09%5Bindex%3Anumber%5D%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Not%20ok%0Avar%20a%3AThing%20%3D%20%7B%0A%091%3A1%2C%0A%095%3A%20'foo'%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20b%2Fc%20implicit%20index%20signature%0Avar%20b%3AThing%20%3D%20%7B%0A%091%3A1%2C%0A%09foo%3A%20'foo'%0A%7D)

**On a side note:** TypeScript tries to be liberate where it can. You can omit parameters from a function signature. See this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Thingy%20%7B%0A%09a%3A(s%3Astring)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0A%09b%3A(s%3Astring)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Thing%20implements%20Thing%20%7B%0A%09a()%20%7B%20return%20'foo'%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20t%20%3D%20new%20Thing()%3B%0At.a()%3B).